# What was the first printed documentation for Blender?

Tags: documentation

I remember buying a printed documentation from NaN a long time ago. Perhaps it was this one:

[image]
<sup>2000 "official" documentation for Blender 2.0, [source](http://download.blender.org/documentation/oldsite/oldsite.blender3d.org/103_Blender%20news%20The%20official%20Blender%202.0%20guide.html)</sup>

In my memory the book was more in the shades of pink, but I may be wrong. Anybody can confirm this was the first book sold by NaN? (I'm not talking about books written by independent writers, though at this time I doubt there was many authors).

Comment: Interesting find, though I'm not sure this technically classifies as a question about Blender. Perhaps you'll have better luck at https://blenderartists.org

Answer (score 1):

I believe this one is way older and Ton signed it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details about this? What version is it for, when was it published, etc.

Comment: Wel as you can read it is for V 1.5 and it was published by

Comment: Published by Not a Number

Comment: Eindhofen, the Netherlands, 1998